# Why can't I call other functions/commands after running main() from within script?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--desiredrange', '-r', default=1)

def main(desiredrange):
    print(desiredrange)
    print('abcd')

main()
print('!!!!')
```

Running the above code gives me the following in the terminal:

1

abcd

But I do not get

!!!!

This scenario is true for other variations of code that include ANYTHING after the main() function. The script exits after executing this function. This is also true for any function i.e. if I placed the print('!!!!') inside another function, then called that function after main(), the script exits after main(), ignoring the second function.

If I removed 'click', such that the code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    print(1)
    print('abcd')

main()
print('!!!!')
```

I will get the following printed to terminal:

1

abcd

!!!!

I can execute other functions after main(), as well as other commands. I run this script from terminal using ./script.py (applied chmod +x script.py). I also get no errors from BOTH scenarios.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function named `main` that you defined isn't actually the one called directly by the line `main()`. Instead, the two decorators are creating a new value that *wraps* the function. This callable (I don't think it's necessarily a function, but a callable instance of `click.core.Command`; I'm not digging into the code heavily to see exactly what happens.) calls raises `SystemExit` in some way, so that your script exits before the "new" `main` actually returns.

You can confirm this by explicitly catching `SystemExit` raised by `main` and ignoring it. This allows the rest of your script to execute.

```
try:
    main()
except SystemExit:
    pass
print('!!!!')
```

---

Remember that decorator syntax is just a shortcut for function application. With the syntax, you can rewrite your code as

```
import click

def main(desiredrange):
    print(desiredrange)
    print('abcd')

x = main

main = click.command(click.option('--desiredrange', '-r', default=1)(main))

y = main
assert x is not y

main()
print('!!!!')
```

Since the assertion passes, this confirms that the value bound to `main` is not your original function, but something else.

Comment: Your first suggestion works. The second gives my a TypeError: command.<locals>.decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'

Comment: The second one isn't so much a suggestion as more explicit demonstrating that the value of the name `main` is changed by the decorators. Check your parentheses; it works the same for me.

Comment: I see your point. So the part of the error that says 'command.<locals>.decorator()' suggests there should be a value returned from within a decorator that is wrapped by command. It can be assumed (since the line where the error occurs is where the function main() is being called) that this value should come from within main(). Is this a good way to think about it?

Answer (score 2):

The `click` module runs your script in `standalone_mode` which invokes the command and then shuts down the Python interpreter, rather than returning.

You can call your `main` with `standalone_mode=False` and it'll return and then continuing executing your additional statements.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--desiredrange', '-r', default=1)
def main(desiredrange):
    print(desiredrange)
    print('abcd')

main(standalone_mode=False)
print('!!!!')
```

```
> python source.py -r 2
2
abcd
!!!!
```

---

Also check the documentation for [`click.BaseCommand`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.BaseCommand.main):

> `standalone_mode` – the default behavior is to invoke the script in standalone mode. Click will then handle exceptions and convert them into error messages and the function will never return but shut down the interpreter. If this is set to `False` they will be propagated to the caller and the return value of this function is the return value of `invoke()`.

Comment: setting standalone_mode=False works. The first answer by chepner works as well. So I need to figure out which is to select as the answer; they both work and seem technically correct considering the documentation for click.BaseCommand.

Comment: @dvines Accept whatever fits the code style you like in your own work, I don't do this for the accepts. :)